# Capture EditText Changes in MVVMCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a `Person` Object where I am passing this object from `ViewModel A` to `ViewModel B`.

In the `View B` display this information as follows.

```
 <EditText
     style="@style/InputNumbersEditText"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="36dp"
     local:MvxBind="Text EditPerson.Age, Converter=Nullable, ConverterParameter='0.0'" />

 <EditText
     style="@style/InputNumbersEditText"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="36dp"
     local:MvxBind="Text EditPerson.Salary, Converter=Nullable, ConverterParameter='0.0'" />
```

Here is the `EditPerson` property in the `ViewModel B`

```
public Person EditPerson
{
   get { return _editPerson; }
   set
   {
      _editPerson = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => EditPerson);
    }
 }
```

I wonder when I edit any of these `EditText`, in debug mode, it does not hit the `EditPerson` Property at all.

How can I capture `EditText` changes for each box, i.e. `Salary` and `Age`?

Comment: how are you passing the object from VM_A to VM_B? as this is a complex object type adn would require serialisation.

Comment: I am just passing `personId` from `ViewModel A` to `ViewModel B` and then call service again to get the corresponding `Person` object. It works, I could able to see the selected `Person`. It also displays selected Person Salary and Age in the EditText, but when I change the `EditText` such as Age or Salary, it does not hit the `EditPerson` property.

Comment: Why would it hit `EditPerson` ? Why don't you use a simple `onTextChangedListener` for your `EditText`s?

Comment: Could you show us Person class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct property to bind is `EditPerson` instead of Person, as Matt and PlaceHold3r noticed.

But regarding your question, your `EditPerson` setter won´t fire when changing Age or Salary of the Person object. It will only get fired if you reassign the whole object, i.e: `ViewModel.EditPerson = new Person();`

If you want to detect changes to Age or Salary, your Person object needs to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Then, you can listen to any property change of the Person: Age, Salary, etc.

**UPDATE**

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _age;
    private decimal _salary;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Age"));
        }
    }

    public decimal Salary
    {
        get { return _salary; }
        set
        {
            _salary = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Salary"));
        }
    }
}

public class YourViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private Person _editPerson;
    public Person EditPerson
    {
        get { return _editPerson; }
        set
        {
            if (_editPerson != null)
                _editPerson.PropertyChanged -= EditPersonOnPropertyChanged;

            _editPerson = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => EditPerson);

            _editPerson.PropertyChanged += EditPersonOnPropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void EditPersonOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        switch (propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName)
        {
            case "Salary":
                Debug.WriteLine("Salary has changed");
                break;

            case "Age":
                Debug.WriteLine("Age has changed");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed as following, but still not changing, I cannot able to hit EditPerson when I change any edittext such as age or gender.  `local:MvxBind="Text EditPerson.Age, Converter=Nullable, ConverterParameter='0.0'"` You could also see changes in my question.

Comment: Are you sure you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in your Person object? Please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

First guess, since I don't see more info yet. You bind on Person, but your Person ViewModels name is EditPerson. So try this:

```
 local:MvxBind="Text EditPerson.Age, Converter=Nullable, ConverterParameter='0.0'"
```

As the other stated this is not the full solution. The reason why I asked for your Person class is to see, if `Person` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This is usual way (in MvvmCross are also other solutions possible) to let the EditTexts listen to changes in your viewmodel. In your property setters of Person you must call

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => EditPerson);
```

and then you can set your breakpoint on this position

Comment: I have changed as following, but still not changing, I cannot able to hit EditPerson when I change any edittext such as age or gender.  `local:MvxBind="Text EditPerson.Age, Converter=Nullable, ConverterParameter='0.0'"` You could also see changes in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The editText will never change the EditPerson property of your ViewModel even if you use:

```
 local:MvxBind="Text EditPerson.Age, Converter=Nullable, ConverterParameter='0.0'"
```

The reason being is the property that is being changed by the editText is `Age` which belongs to your `Person` class. You can pick up the change in the `set` of your `Person` class.

Comment: I think then I misunderstood the question ;)

Comment: I have changed to `EditPerson`, but still same.

Comment: I have changed as following, but still not changing, I cannot able to hit EditPerson when I change any edittext such as age or gender.  `local:MvxBind="Text EditPerson.Age, Converter=Nullable, ConverterParameter='0.0'"` You could also see changes in my question.